# print timestamp and session name in textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, session

I am trying to design a form to update certain data. For audit purpose I need to print a timestamp & session username in the textarea box. I am trying to use the `onclick()` Javascript  function. But unable to format the date to just display date & time. Also I am not sure how to print the session username.

I am using HTML, PHP, MySQL & Javascript here.

This is the $_SESSION declaration are the top of the page.

```
<?php
    include 'config/connectDB.php';
    session_start();
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM alerts WHERE'.  " alert_id = '$id'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);   

?>
```

This is the Javascript function in the

```
<script>
        function myFunction(event) {
            var n = new Date();
            document.getElementById("notes").innerHTML = n;
        }
</script>
```

This is the textarea where I need to print the date, time & $_SESSION name everytime anyone clicks in the textarea.

```
<div class="control-group form-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <label>Notes</label><br>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="notes" name="notes" value="<?php echo $row['notes'];?>" rows="5" cols="50" onclick="myFunction(event)" required>
        </textarea>
        <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this `<textarea> Your value </textarea>`

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="notes" name="notes" " rows="5" cols="50" onclick="myFunction(event)" required>
<?php echo $row['notes'];?>
        </textarea>
```

Comment: I know how to pull values from the DB table. I am stuck about how to print date , time & session username